# Is there any practical usage of using unity container to add, resolve dependencies in the controller itself?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

In the MVC application i am working with these days, they have registered and resolved all the Interface/Concrete class dependencies inside the controller itself. I read about ioc and dependency inversion and found that the thing that has been done is completely non-useful. Since it would anyway not allow the application to leverage benefits of IoC example mocking, unit testing and would also add cost of adding/resolving the dependencies unnecessarily. Below is code sample:

```
HomeController

   using(IUnityContainer container= new UnityContainer())
   {
     container.RegisterType<IRepository1, Repository1>()
     IRepository1 _repos1 = container.Resolve<IRepository1>();
   }
```

I dont see any point of doing all this stuff if we dont get any benefit out of this. Can someone please tell if this could be of any use now or in future?

If not, i am planning to simply instantiate them with concrete implementations or like:

```
IRepository1 repos1= new Repository1();
```

Please ignore the syntax.

(I have editted the code snippet now.)

Comment: Is repos1 instantiated in the controller?

Comment: This might be possible to answer if the syntax was correct...

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "inside the container itself"?

Comment: I have edited the problem now. Is using Unity container like this anyways helpful? OR I should simply use IRepos1= new Repos1() directly?

Comment: Please post code that at least has a passing chance of working. The code posted creates `container` in a `using` statement that disposes of `container` before `container.Resolve` is called. This would result in a run-time exception.

Comment: you shouldn't ever resolve to your repository, you should resolve to a ServiceClass that is constructed using IRepository (or takes IRepository as a parameter in it's construction).. that is where the actual injection occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a container to first register and then resolve a concrete type doesn't make any sense, there is no benefit of that. You are still coupled to a concrete type. You could possibly argue that the container helps to match all constructor parameters with instances of respective types but this doesn't count as a real benefit in my opinion.

If you really don't plan to make use of abstractions that are resolved externally, then yes, you can safely remove the bloating container code and create concrete instances, just as you have presented.

Comment: hmm.... or, you could (and should) register the types in `global.asax` and resolve in your controllers...

Comment: @BrettCaswell: that would make proper use of the container and this is not what the question is about. The question is specifically about misusing the container and possible dropping the usage in such specific case.

Comment: haha, still... "new is glue" .. developers should be working toward decoupling the construction and initialization of instance data with usages of it.

Comment: but yeah, there's absolutely no benefit in the current implementation: creating the container, registering the types (with no LifetimeManager object to boot), and then resolving it in the next line. It's just a convoluted way to construct an instance of repository1, which apparently doesn't have/require parameters in it's construction.. the real benefit of IoC is completely lost if you have to construct instances that are then used in the construction of the instance at the time you're attempting to resolve to it...

Answer (score 0):

The immediate answer to this question is your current implementation causes more overhead and performance impact then doing a standard construction, and you should remove it; or redesign your implementation of Unity.

---

The following is an example of the benefit of injection that occurs when resolving to a type that has a dependency of another type that is registered with the unity container.

```
public class UserService 
{
    internal readonly IRepository _repository;
    public UserService(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    //Service Method that exposes 'Domain Logic'
    public void CreateUser(string FirstName) 
    {
        _repository.Insert<User>(new User() { FirstName = FirstName }); //Assumes there is a Generic method, Insert<T>, that attaches instances to the underline context.
    }

    public User GetUser(string FirstName)
    {
        return _repository.Query<User>().FirstOrDefault(user => user.FirstName == FirstName); // assumes there is a Generic method, Query<T>, that returns IQueryable<T> on IRepository
    }
}
```

register the types (probably in a singleton pattern at Global.asax)

```
//Resolver is an instance of UnityContainer
Resolver.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()); 
Resolver.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>();
```

Then the logic in your controller is like so:

```
var service = Resolver.Resolve<IUserService>(); //the resolver will resolve IRepository to an instance as well...
var user = service.GetUser("Grant");
```

Comment: I replaced `IRepository1` with `IRepository` in this snippet

Comment: also, your MVC application shouldn't even be able to reference `UserService` or `Repository`, which also means Unity doesn't belong in your MVC application.. your application should be completely agnostic to the implementation of those interfaces or **infrastructure layer/teir** concerns

Comment: What I mean is, you should create another project (class library) that your MVC application will use as a dependency assembly/reference, have Unity added (via nuget probably) to that class library project. that project will reference infrastructure layer and domain layer (interfaces and 'some' implementing class - which should be in separate projects themselves).. assuming your Domain Service interfaces are in the same project as your entities/dtos/models.. you should have at least 4 projects